# Odoo11 TypeError: this.pos is undefined with a screen widget triggered by a button action

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale, qweb

Create a screen "custom-screen" extended from screen widget with a template show a paragraph of lorem and return object of screen widget so it can be called from other widgets.

This screen I want to trigger this screen widget from a button. The screen showed but I got this error "this.pos is undefined" when the button clicked

**TypeError: this.pos is undefined**

```
TypeError: this.pos is undefined
http://localhost:8069/web/content/1394-95d31f5/point_of_sale.assets.js:337
Traceback:
show@http://localhost:8069/web/content/1394-95d31f5/point_of_sale.assets.js:337:1
show_screen@http://localhost:8069/web/content/1394-95d31f5/point_of_sale.assets.js:316:28
button_click@http://localhost:8069/web/content/1394-95d31f5/point_of_sale.assets.js:572:385
renderElement/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/1394-95d31f5/point_of_sale.assets.js:362:203
dispatch@http://localhost:8069/web/content/941-9a091d9/web.assets_common.js:892:378
$event.dispatch@http://localhost:8069/web/content/1394-95d31f5/point_of_sale.assets.js:480:8
add/elemData.handle@http://localhost:8069/web/content/941-9a091d9/web.assets_common.js:865:151
```

[image]

> __mainfest__.py

```
{
    'name': "custom-screen",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",


    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],

    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/custom-screen.xml',

    ],
}
```

> views/templates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/custom-screen/static/src/js/custom.js"></script>

        </xpath>
    </template>

</odoo>

> custom.js

    odoo.define('custom-screen.custom-screen', function (require) {
        "use strict";


        var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
        var gui = require('point_of_sale.gui');

        var Button = screens.ActionButtonWidget.extend({
            template: 'Button',

            button_click: function () {
                var self = this;
                console.log('Button Clicked');
                self.gui.show_screen('custom-screen');

            },

        });

        screens.define_action_button({
            'name': 'button',
            'widget': Button,
        });

        var CustomScreenWidget = screens.ScreenWidget.extend({
            template: 'CustomScreenWidget',

            init: function () {
                console.log("Initialize the custom screen");
            }
        });

        gui.define_screen({
            'name': 'custom-screen',
            'widget': CustomScreenWidget,
        });

        return {
            Button: Button,
            CustomScreenWidget: CustomScreenWidget
        };

    });
```

> static/src/xml/custom-screen.xml

```
<t t-name="Button">
    <span class="control-button">
        <!--<i class="fa fa-print"></i>-->
        Open Custom Screen
    </span>
</t>

<t t-name="CustomScreenWidget">
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus alias, aliquid cupiditate dignissimos, doloribus, enim error eum fugiat id nisi odit quibusdam quo repellat repellendus sed vitae voluptatem. Distinctio, nemo.</p>
    </div>
</t>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide whole traceback of error stack here. Also this error is raised because you try to access current value of 'pos' object but it is not defined so this error is getting raised.

Comment: I edit the question to include the whole traceback of the error stack

Comment: Try to debug this code via console's inspect element at the time of opening screen.